# Word that refers to the "quantity/amount" of floor?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, measuring-units

For example you would say:

> Miles and miles of road
>
> Tons and tons of food

How about when referring to the floor inside a house (given that the house is relatively big)?

Example:

> [...] and [...] of plywood floor

(Maybe *squares*?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would say:

> Acres and acres of plywood floor

Because floorage is an areal measure.

---

**Afternote**

<sup>(*Text rescued from potentially ephemeral comments.*)</sup>

Because I couldn’t see how the asker’s two exemplars of *tons of food* and *miles of road* made any **literal** (read: “literal-literal” as opposed to hyperbolic) sense in the case of your run-of-the-mill single-family home, I chose the answer that seemed best-matched to those two in scope and tenor.

For rather unlike scenarios, compare these two scenarios:

1. Do you new give homeowners a **per-square-foot** pricing break for hardwood flooring installations above a certain **square footage**?
2. Wow dude, you’ve got like **acres and acres** of hardwood floors here hidden under your wall-to-wall carpeting!

   Don’t bother stopping at the grocery store: we’ve got **tons of food** here.

   Gosh, your driveway is **like miles long**!

Comment: In colloquial usage a mixed metaphor is quite common:  "Your apartment has *tons* of floor space!"

Comment: *Acres and acres of land* seems to be more correct.

Comment: -1 *Miles of road* & *tons of food* are not unrealistic; *acres of floor(space)* is sheer hyperbole.

Comment: @kris, Only for an ordinary house.  A large mansion will have an acre or two of floor space, and factories routinely have tens of acres of floor.

Comment: Yes it's hyperbole - and it's used by people in common language. Also expressions such as room to swing a cat (or not) are often used. Also you could refer to other uses that require a lot of space "you could play a game of cricket!" etc...

Comment: @Kris You appear to have confused the not-unheard-of **acres** of flooring with **square miles** of it. Not to put too fine a point on it, but you are wrong to the point of appearing foolish, and your downvote was uninformed and unwarranted. The buildings of China’s  Forbidden City have 37 acres of flooring and those of Versailles have 16½ acres of it; even my local Whole Foods Market has 1.8 acres of flooring! Remember that while a square mile is 640 acres, **an acre is only 4,840 square yards,** so 43,560 square feet. “Acreage of flooring” is quite like “miles of road” or “tons of food”.

Comment: @tchrist: more likely than a confusion of units, Kris just has a lower standard than you do of what constitutes a "relatively big" house.

Comment: @Steve: Maybe. One thing is sure, though: his standard for what constitutes a poor answer seems somewhat lower than almost anyone else's on this site.

Comment: @Robusto: sure, I also think Kris was mistaken to assume that the questioner didn't want hyperbole. But tchrist isn't saying that, he's using Versailles as an example of a relevant "house" ;-)

Comment: I generally give tchrist the benefit of the doubt when it comes to his facility with English.

Comment: @SteveJessop If a farmer can raise so many tons of food in a year, or a construction company can lay so many miles of road a year, then surely a flooring company can lay so many acres of floor annually. Conic sections need not apply.

Comment: @tchrist: that's true, but the question specifically mentions the floor of a house. Not of a palace, not of a thousand houses supplied by Acme Flooring Co during a year. The answer's still correct of course, but the reason is *because it is idiomatic English as a hyperbole*, not because "palaces and flooring companies both literally achieve multiple acres". It just seems bizarre to me to insist on a context other than that presented in the question. Had the question specifically said, "I want to speak literally about a house, not in hyperbole", *then* I would certainly downvote this answer.

Comment: @SteveJessop Because I couldn’t see how the asker’s two exemplars of *tons of food* and *miles of road* made any **literal** (read: “literal-literal” as opposed to hyperbolic) sense in the case of your run-of-the-mill single-family home, I chose the answer that seemed best-matched to those two in scope and tenor. Perhaps compare “Wow dude, you’ve got like acres and acres of hardwood floors here hidden under your wall-to-wall carpeting!” with “Do you new give homeowners a per-square-foot pricing break for hardwood floor installations above a certain square footage?” for rather unlike scenarios.

Comment: I think *acres* is as good an answer as you'll get. I think the trouble is that *acre* is the smallest common measure of area that isn't a modification of a length measure such as *square feet* or *square yards*. *square feet and square feet* sounds stupid and *acres and acres* is just way too big to apply to a house, even a "relatively big" one, even hyperbolically.

Comment: @Henry74 Even a football field is about 1⅜ acres.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, people will often refer to large amounts of "square footage"; as in "this apartment is huge! You have a lot of open square footage".

Answer (score 0):

Here are two terms for the area of a floor, in particular:

- [***floor area***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_area_(building)), as in *a large floor area*
- ***floor space***, as in *lots of floor space*

If you really want to say *plywood floor*, then do so, but there is no special term for expressing the amount of floor space (area) - no more than for your *tons and tons of food*. You can say *acres and acres of plywood floor*, but there is nothing special about *acre* in this regard.

There are lots of different units of area, including "*square*" followed by **any** unit of length - *square lightyears*, for example.

Comment: I do not believe that this answers the question. What was asked for was a unit, particularly something that can be used in a hyperbolic or exaggerated manner.

Comment: I answered that as well. There is no particular unit for area - there are lots of units for area, from hectares to square nanometers and beyond.